# Automatic Transmission Fluid Color

Tags: automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid

I changed my Transmission fluid with a system that drain and fill simultaneously a week ago,
and I checked the color Today,
Please See the picture attached,
It seems too dark, is there any problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does it smell?

Comment: The smell is Normal, there is no any burnt smell, Transmission works normal and better than before too.

Comment: Then I'd suggest there's no issues. The fluid probably cleaned out the rest of the gunk left behind from before. If it is truly worrisome to you, then get it done again.

Comment: Also keep in mind that it's nearly impossible to replace all the transmission fluid.  Even when you drop the pan, there is quite a bit of the old fluid left in the torque converter.

Comment: Some vehicles procedure calls for drain and fill, then drive, then drain and fill again. Sometimes even a third time.